# IIS web service failing to launch/run py Python files

Tags: python, web-services, iis, process, windows-server-2022

We're replacing a Windows 2012 server with a new Windows 2022 server, and the same IIS web service works on old but not new.

- IIS
- Windows 2022
- C# webservice apppool runs under AD service account
- Webservice runs py (Python) files using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
- ArcGIS Pro software is involved as part of the py file script

New server works if the service account is logged in interactively (rdp) AND the app pool has been recycled (Postman returns 0 in the soap response).

If service account is logged out and the app pool is not recycled, Postman returns "no application associated with this file type."

If the appeal is then recycled, Postman returns code 112 in the soap response.  Not sure if that 112 is meaningful...if it's an IIS error code, a Python error code, or something else.

I manually set the file type association for the py extension to the installed Python exe, while logged in as the service account, and "abc.py" file will run in a command window.

This is a weird one...any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks for trying. We have a case with Microsoft. Their IIS team bailed on it after some very basic troubleshooting, so I’m waiting to hear from the next team it gets assigned to. Feels like it’s not getting the attention it needs so I may bump it up to a Sev B.